# Show hidden div in page after clicking link to open the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an HTML page in which a hidden div becomes visible when a button is clicked. Something like this:

```
$('#display').click(function(){
    $('#itemList').removeClass('hide');
    ...
})
```

On another page, there is a link which when clicked takes the user back to the earlier page, and the element with id=`'itemList'` on that page has to become visible. The code is something like this:

```
<a href='firstHTML.php'> View items</a>
```

I am not sure what else to add to the code to make the other page appear with the previously hidden element visible. Can somebody help please?

Comment: `$('#itemList').addClass('hide')` on anchor click

Comment: you will most likely have to use a global variable that persists through the pages, or you will have to use a URL parameter.

Comment: You can write your values to cookies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most probable solution is localStorage .Where as you may also implement Cookies or string query to pass value to other page.

I am showing the use of localstorage , you may store the id in localStorage on click of anchor as below

```
<a href='firstHTML.php' data-showId='itemList'> View items</a>
```

Now bind event on anchor

```
$("[data-showId]").bind('click',function(){
    var idToShow=$(this).attr('data-showId');
    if(idToShow)
      store('visibleId', idToShow);
});
```

Now all you need to define these functions .

```
   function setup() {
        var tmp = get('visibleId');
        if (tmp)
          showDiv(tmp);
    } 
    function showDiv(cls) {
        $("#"+cls).removeClass('hide');
    }
    function get(name) {
        if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
          return localStorage.getItem(name);
        } else {
          window.alert('Please use a modern browser to properly view this template!');
        }
    }
    function store(name, val) {
        if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
          localStorage.setItem(name, val);
        } else {
          window.alert('Please use a modern browser to properly view this template!');
        }
    }
```

Now call setup() on dom ready..

Comment: localStorage is a great solution to this problem. I wouldn't advocate the alerts for older browsers, though; better just to not support this functionality than impose an unnecessary user requirement.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would use the jQuery function to hide/show the List instead of using an own CSS class for it:

```
$('#display').click(function(){
    $('#itemList').show();
    ...
})
```

Then a possible approach for your problem could be to use a get Parameter for this, for example:

```
<a href='firstHTML.php?list=show'> View items</a>
```

And with jQuery

1. Create a helperfunction (Taken from [Get url parameter jquery Or How to Get Query String Values In js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery)):

   ```
   $.urlParam = function(name) {

     var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);

     if (results==null){
       return null;
     }else{
      return results[1] || 0;
     } 
   }
   ```
2. Read out the property:

   ```
   var listStatus = $.urlParam('list');
   ```
3. Unhide the list in case it should be shown:

   ```
   $( document ).ready(function() { 
     if(listStatus == 'show') {
       $('#itemList').show();
     }
   });
   ```